# re.split doesnt work properly with a string coming from excel cell

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, split

I have a string:

> 05-01-2015 12:27 - KH - (KH) Igangværende - Opringning - 13-11 00:00 
>   Fangede RLI på hans mobil. Ring igen kl. 15  19-11-2014 11:17 - KH -
>   (KH) Igangværende - Opringning - 13-11 00:00  Gik på svarer igen og
>   lagt besked til RLI at ringe tilbage.  12-11-2014 09:38 - KH - (KH)
>   Igangværende - Opringning - 13-11 00:00  12-11-2014 09:32 - KH - (KH)
>   Igangværende - Opringning - 15-10 00:00  Forsøgt RLI igen og lagt
>   besked om han vil ringe.  14-10-2014 13:14 - KH - (KH) Igangværende -
>   Opringning - 15-10 00:00  14-10-2014 13:10 - KH - (KH) Igangværende -
>   Opringning - 14-10 00:00  Lagt besked til RLI at ringe  14-10-2014
>   13:06 - KH - (KH) Igangværende - Opringning - 14-10 00:00  test

I parse this string into pieces so that each piece starts with dates. For this purpose, as solved in [my other post about my task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012533/parsing-string-according-to-dates-in-python) I benefit from regex like :

```
match = re.search(r' (?=\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})', text)
```

When i write above string directly to variable **text** in code, there is no problem. But if i obtain this text from a cell in excel file with xlrd or others, i cant get values properly. I tried cell values with encode/decode things also. But i only get the text as a whole in match[0]. There are no splitted match[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012533/parsing-string-according-to-dates-in-python), match[2] or others. Here is how i try to get text from excel file :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("liste1.xlsx")

# get the first worksheet
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# read a cell
cell = first_sheet.cell(1,5)

text=cell.value
match = re.split(r' (?=\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})', text)

print match[0]
```

Could you help me with this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the [documentation on `re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.search) - it only finds the first match. You're probably looking for something like `re.findall`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Comment: but it works when text="05-01-2015 12:27 - KH - (KH) Igangværende - Opringning - 13-11 00:00 Fangede RLI....."

Comment: When same text is obtained from excell cell, it doesnt

Comment: And its not re.search, but re.split

Comment: what do you mean it's `re.split` and not `re.search`?..Are you talking about your posted expression above or what?

Comment: Yes. If you look at other post that i gave its link above, i have a task and its already solved with re.split. The problem here is, exactly same text is coming from a cell value in excel file and this time doesnt work the way i need.

Comment: So you are splitting here not searching...correct?

Comment: im talking about splitting, yes

Comment: Then you might want to mention this in your question, that you want to split not search...it's different

Comment: But i never talk about searching in my post and in the other post its already solved in splitting. I think what i need to fix here is clear.

Comment: Also, you might want to post the code related to how you read that data from excel cell...it's relevant here

Comment: ok. i ll put now. But its standart xlrd read process.

Comment: Is that whole string in one cell?

Comment: Yes , all of it in one cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81379/discussion-between-khalil-ammour---and-sansal-birbas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding a line that removes non-printing characters from cell as already stated in this post [Unwanted Character in Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423593/unwanted-character-in-excel-cell-in-python) :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("liste1.xlsx")

# get the first worksheet
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# read a cell
cell = first_sheet.cell(1,5)

text= re.sub(r"[\r\n\t\x07\x0b]", "", cell.value)
match = re.split(r' (?=\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})', text)

print match[0]
print match[1]
print match[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `repr(text)`?

Comment: What it does exactly?

Comment: "Return a string containing a printable representation of an object." https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#repr

Comment: No unfortunately. Let me tell you. There is an interestin situation. When i copy that text from this post i wrote in stackoverflow it does successfully. But if i copy same content from excel cell in libreoffice it doesnt work.

Comment: Yes, that is probably, because there are control characters in that cell that you can't see on screen. So, when printed on screen the control characters are automatically removed, but when you read from that cell, you have to remove those manually.

Comment: Have you tried `re.split(r' (?=\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})', repr(textfromcell))`?

Comment: Sorry, I have never worked with LibreOffice, but that is my guess. There are control characters that need be removed before using the regex or you need to change the pattern slightly.